# Get the changed context in a telerik rich text box

Tags: wpf, telerik

How can I get only the changed context of a telerik radrichtextbox in WPF? For example, I need to get the changes that a user made in a text like writing/deleting characters. I am using DocumentContextChanged event to detect that a change has occurred, but I cannot get the content of the actual change.

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing details about the context e.g. how you have implemented relevant controls and their backing data.

Comment: To answer my question: I've contacted telerik support team, they informed me that currently getting only the changed context in a telerik RadRichTextBox is not supported. I can use the current position of the cursor to get the data.However, it might be a complicated process,so a solution is to reload the entire document whenever a change occurs.